# Do two magnets attract each other stronger than one magnet and a metal plate?

Tags: electromagnetism

In the car, I use a magnetic mount to hold the mobile phone, but it keeps falling when the road is not so smooth.

I use a magnet mount to the dashboard and a small metal plate attached to the phone case. Will using another magnet instead of the plate hold better?

Comment: Depends on how "magnetic" the other magnet is and the type of metal you use

Comment: Get a better mount! I use a magnetic mount while off-roading and it works just fine...

Comment: @AaronStevens not sure i understand. can you elaborate more please?

Comment: You need to include more information. Your question is not currently answerable in a meaningful way. Different magnets are stronger than other magnets, and different metals have different magnetic properties. Your question is like asking "Is one number larger than another number", to which my answer would be "It depends on which numbers you are looking at."

Comment: @AaronStevens i am aware of that. However, giving the fact the "dashboard magnet" is the same one in both cases, and the only difference is what attached to the phone. Some kind of metal (can not say the exact metal) or rather another magnet. Are you saying that the answer is not clear, and that the additional magnet can be both weaker or stronger comparing a metal plate?